# Definition of piecewise differentiable curve in do Carmo: Riemannian Geometry; onesided derivative $\lim_{t\to a^+} c'(t)$ of a curve $c:[a,b]\to M$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Do Carmo defines a piecewise differential curve in the following manner:

> A piecewise differentiable curve is a continuous mapping $c:[a,b]\to M$ of a closed interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ into $M$ satisfying the following condition: there exists a partition
> $$a=t_0<t_1<\dots <t_{k-1}=b$$
> of $[a,b]$ such that the restrictions $c\rvert_{[t_i, t_{i+1}]},i=0,\dots,k-1,$ are differentiable. We say that $c$ joins the points $c(a)$ and $c(b)$. $c(t_i)$ is called a vertex of $c$, and the angle formed by $\lim_{t\to t_i^+} c'(t)$ with $\lim_{t\to t_i^-} c'(t)$ is called the vertex angle at $c(t_i)$; here $\lim_{t\to t_i^+}$ ($\lim_{t\to t_i^-})$ signifies that $t$ approaches $t_i$ trough values above (below) that of $t_i$.

As far as I know, do Carmo hasn't defined what is meant by differentiability of a curve $c: [t_i, t_{i+1}]\to M$ on a closed set. If I understand the answer given by John B in [On the definition of piecewise differentiable curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2491582/776794) correctly, it means that $c$, as a curve on $(t_i, t_{i+1})$, is differentiable and that the one-sided derivatives exist at the endpoints $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$. However, how would one go about calculating these derivatives or defining their existence? We have
$$c'(t) f = (f \circ c)'(t)=\frac{d}{dt} (f \circ c)(t) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c(t+h))-f(c(t))}{h}\quad \forall f\in C^{\infty}(M), t\in (t_i,t_{i+1}).$$

Does that mean that $\lim_{t\to t_i^+} c'(t)$ exists if

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(c(t_i^++h))-f(c(t_i^+))}{h}$$
exists for all $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$? This doesn't seem correct to me since a definition without the use of $f$ would be preferable.

John B also mentioned that the differentiability defined by the existence of the one-sided derivatives is equivalent to the fact that there exists a differentiable extension of $c$ which is defined on a larger open interval. Could someone provide me with a reference for this fact?

Comment: I see, thank you! But how is the right-hand derivative for a curve on a manifold defined?

Comment: Your domain is $[a,b]$, so it "makes sense" there in the same way as usual, just use charts to get into $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I removed my previous comment because it contains an error.  The idea was close to right but I was making additional unstated assumptions.

Comment: Which assumptions did you make? They might be satisfied in the context of the book. And what "usual" way are you refering to? Differentiability in do Carmo was always defined exclusively in the context of open (sub-)sets.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Do Carmo wanted piecewise $C^1$ rather than just piecewise differentiable here, otherwise $\lim c'$ need not exist.

Comment: What does piecewise $C^1$ mean in this context? And Do Carmo usually assumes that differentiable means $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: @Mandelbrot I gave the Lie groups version, which is nice because you can operate/translate within the manifold.  That won't work generally, sorry.  You'll need someone sharper to help.

Comment: Regardless, I am grateful for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything here is basically generalising the $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ version to manifolds using charts.  One-sided derivatives are defined by, for example, the equivalence class of curves version:

**Definition**: The one-sided derivative (from the right) of a curve $c\colon[0,\ell)\to M^n$ at $0$, $c'_+(0)\in T_{c(0)}M$ is the equivalence class $[\gamma]$ of curves $\gamma\colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$, $\gamma(0)=c(0)$ that has $(\varphi\circ\gamma)'(0)=(\varphi\circ c)'_+(0)$ for any (hence all) charts $\varphi$ at $c(0)$.  Similarly one-sided derivative from the left $c'_-$

For extendability, again we only need to do the case $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions and extend to $\mathbb{R}^n$ on each coordinate and to $M$ by charts.

**Recall**: For any differentiable $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with one-sided derivatives $f'_+\colon[a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f'_-\colon(a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, you can extend to a differentiable $\tilde{f}\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\tilde{f}(t)=
\begin{cases}
f(a)+(t-a)f'_+(a) & t<a\\
f(t) & t\in[a,b]\\
f(b)+(t-b)f'_-(b) & t>b
\end{cases}
$$
Moreover, if $f'_{\pm}$ are continuous then $\tilde{f}$ is $C^1$ (and you can extend this to higher-order derivatives suitable degree-$k$ polynomials instead of linears).  This allows us to define piecewise $C^k$ function to $\mathbb{R}$.  For $C^\infty$ you will need to use some bump functions (exercise).

Comment: Thank you! Does $(\varphi \circ c)'_+(0)$ mean $\lim_{h\to 0^+} (\varphi \circ c)'(h)$?

Comment: And could you maybe provide a reference for your definition of the one-sided derivative?

Comment: No, I'm using $(\varphi\circ c)'_+(0):=\lim_{h\downarrow 0} ((\varphi\circ c)(h)-(\varphi\circ c)(0))/h$, the usual one-sided derivative you learn from first course of real analysis.  Didn't assume the usual derivative has a limit at $0$ unless explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a curve $c$ on a closed interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable iff $c$ can be extended to a differentiable curve on some open open interval $J\subset \mathbb{R}$ which contains $[a,b]$. It can be shown that this is equivalent to the fact that given any parametrization $x:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n \to M$ with $c(a)/c(b) \in x(U)$, the component functions $x^{-1} \circ c(t) = (x^1(t),...,x^n(t))$ have one-sided derivatives of all orders at $a/b$. For reference, see page 55 in the the chapter about Vector Fields Along Curves of "Riemmanian Manifolds" by John Lee.